# Phonegap - How to download file using webview in phonegap application?

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am new to phonegap application development. I need to download a large pdf file(around 40MB) using webview and store it into the application specific folder(i.e outside users should not have access to it). After I download it I need to open/read it in my application by using default PDF reader installed into my device.

These I have done into native platform(Android) , but don't have idea how to do in PhoneGap applications.

I don't want use Cordova/phonegap plugin to access my native code, since I want to run it in all mobile platforms.

Please provide some code examples or links to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the File API, in fact, the File Transfer download option https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md

Example:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/yourFile.pdf");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    downloadPath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false
);
```